# Simple XML on Android - class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E>?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to the simple xml library. I really like it but I have got a problem.

Here are my classes (some code has been removed to make it more concise):

```
@Root
@ElementList
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{

public void ToXml() throws Exception{
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            File file = new File("somewhere in my file system");
            serializer.write(this, file);
    }
}
```

¬

```
@Root
public abstract class MediaEntry implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Element
            public String Title;
            @Element
            public String Description;
            @Element
            public String Url;
            @Element
            public String LocalPath;

            public MediaEntry(String title, String description, 
                              String url, String localPath) {
                            Title= title;
                            Description= description;
                            Url= url;
                            LocalPath= localPath;
            }
}
```

¬

```
public class VideoEntry extends MediaEntry {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public VideoEntry(String title, String description, 
                              String url, String localPath) {

            super(title, description, url, localPath);
            }
}
```

When I instantiate MyArrayList add some VideoEntries and call ToXml, I only get an empty root ie.

```
<MyArrayList />
```

How to I solve this? Is it something to do with the fact that MyArrayList is generic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The List has to be a member of an element (and no seperate class) to get the desired behaviour, you can set the ElementList inline, so there is no parent element.

```
@Root
public class MyArrayList<E> {   
    @ElementList(inline=true)
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();

    public boolean add(E entry) {
        return list.add(entry);
    }

    public void ToXml() throws Exception {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        File file = new File("somewhere in my file system");
        serializer.write(this, file);
    }
}
```

Just thought of another solution which may even be better (you have access to all the List functions - but I'm not sure if there are any side-effects, so i leave my original solution)

```
@Root
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {      
    @ElementList(inline=true)
    MyArrayList<E> list = this;

    public void ToXml() throws Exception {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        File file = new File("somewhere in my file system");
        serializer.write(this, file);
    }
}
```

To deserialize you have to declare for SimpleXML, whicht element is used for which constructor-parameter:

```
@Root
public abstract class MediaEntry implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Element
    public String Title;
    @Element
    public String Description;
    @Element
    public String Url;
    @Element
    public String LocalPath;

    public MediaEntry(@Element(name = "Title") String title,
            @Element(name = "Description") String description,
            @Element(name = "Url") String url,
            @Element(name = "LocalPath") String localPath) {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        Url = url;
        LocalPath = localPath;
    }
}
```

Btw, if you are just start programming Java, you might consider reading the Java code conventions - it is not a good practice to start method- and variablenames with a capital letter (so you can prevent getting used to bad habits ;-))

Comment: This is great but I am having problems deserializing now... Can you suggest a way to do this?

Comment: This is the error I get org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class VideoEntry

Comment: @PhilippWendt I'm trying to use this, but when I try to deserialize type E is always an object instead of the real type of the list. What could I be doing wrong?